# How to convert a function into pipe-friendly functions?

Tags: r, tidyverse, magrittr

I'm trying to convert the following function into a pipe-friendly function. But it is made up of strings. I'm not sure where to begin.

```
library(MplusAutomation)

pathmodel <- mplusObject(
   TITLE = "MplusAutomation Example - Path Model;",
   MODEL = "
     mpg ON hp;
     wt by disp drat;",
   OUTPUT = "CINTERVAL;",
   rdata = mtcars)
```

I've tried this format, but I'm not sure which does not work and I'm not sure how to create this so that it works with pipes.

```
mplus <- function(data, title, on, by, output) {
  mplusObject(TITLE = as.character(title),
              MODEL = paste(on, "/n", by),
              OUTPUT = as.character(output),
              rdata = data)
  
}
```

This is what I'm trying to achieve by the end.

```
mplus %>%
  data(mtcars) %>%
  title("example - path model") %>%
  predictors("mpg on hp") %>%
  latentvars("wt by disp drat") %>%
  output(cinterval)
```

Comment: Typing `pathmodel` returns `>Error in summary.mplusObject(x) : 
  isFALSE(is.null(object$results)) is not TRUE`. Pipes are used to chain multiple functions in an orderly fashion. There are no functions called `on`, `output` etc for you to pipe. Those are arguments of only 1 function i.e `mplusObject`. You cannot pipe the arguments.

Comment: I see. I edited my expected code to allow direct quotations. For piping the arguments, should I create new functions which I can then use together. If so, how would that look like. Even a simple suggestion would help, if not the whole solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have pipable function, then you would need a pipeble object. Here we just stote the values in the a list. Something like

```
new_mplus <- function(data=NA) {
  x <- list(TITLE=NA, MODEL=NA, OUTPUT=NA, predictors=NA, latent=NA, rdata=data)
  class(x) <- "mplus"
  x
}

is_mplus <- function(x) {
  "mplus" %in% class(x)
}

mplus <- function(data) {
  stopifnot(is.data.frame(data))
  new_mplus(data)
}

title <- function(x, title) {
  stopifnot(is_mplus(x))
  x$TITLE <- title
  x
}

predictors <- function(x, predictors) {
  stopifnot(is_mplus(x))
  x$predictors <- predictors
  x
}

latentvars <- function(x, latent) {
  stopifnot(is_mplus(x))
  x$latent <- latent
  x
}

output <- function(x, output) {
  stopifnot(is_mplus(x))
  x$OUTOUT <- output
  x
}
```

And then you call it with

```
mtcars %>%
  mplus() %>%
  title("example - path model") %>%
  predictors("mpg on hp") %>%
  latentvars("wt by disp drat") %>%
  output("cinterval")
```

The list will keep track of all your values. Then you'd just need to have a function to execute it

```
execute <- function(x) {
  mplusObject(TITLE = x$TITLE
              MODEL = paste(x$predictors, "/n", x$latent),
              OUTPUT = x$OUTPUT,
              rdata = x$data)
}

mtcars %>%
  mplus() %>%
  title("example - path model") %>%
  predictors("mpg on hp") %>%
  latentvars("wt by disp drat") %>%
  output("cinterval") %>% 
  execute()
```

Pipes are all about passing an object from one function to the next so you need some sort of object to pass that will store all the values. With `dplyr` you are passing around a `tibble` and with `ggplot2` you are creating a `ggplot` object.

Answer (score 1):

This is what you could do to make this function dynamic :

```
mplus <- function(data, title, on, by, output) {
  mplusObject(TITLE = title,
              MODEL = paste(on, "/n", by),
              OUTPUT = output,
              rdata = data)
}
```

and then call it as :

```
mtcars %>%
  mplus("example - path model", "mpg on hp", "wt by disp drat", "CINTERVAL")
```

Comment: Great. Would it be possible to split the ```mplusObject``` function into multiple functions to use it as pipes?

Comment: You need to create different functions for each one then. I think Mr.Flick's answer shows you how.